# ElasticSearch range query: Finding values around a number

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to construct an ES query for a range around a target number. For example, if I entered 10000 I would want 1000 results with #10000 in the middle. The problem is that the results aren't complete, i.e. there may or may not be something with value 9999, so I can't just search between 9500 and 10500. My approach was to do two different queries, one with size 500 finding all values less than or equal to 10000 and sorted descending, and a second query of size 500 finding all values greater 10000 and sorted ascending. Unfortunately it doesn't work the way I want it to, and I end up not getting #10000 at all. My queries look like this:

```
query1 = {
    'size': 500,
    'sort': [{'id': {'order': 'desc', 'unmapped_type': 'boolean'}}],
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'filter': [
                {'match_phrase': {'group_id': int(request.args['group'])}},
                {'range': {'id': {'lte': int(request.args['id'])}}}
            ]
        }
    }
}

query2 = {
    'size': 500,
    'sort': [{'id': {'order': 'asc', 'unmapped_type': 'boolean'}}],
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'filter': [
                {'match_phrase': {'group_id': int(request.args['group'])}},
                {'range': {'id': {'gt': int(request.args['id'])}}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is it 10000 in `request.args[id]`?

Comment: Yes, for this example

Comment: What if your match_phrase query causes to skip id 10000.

Comment: The args are passed in based one one specific result, so the group always contains the id I'm targeting.